# Sticky DIV is flickering when used with IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have sticky `div` and use `IntersectionObserver` to detect when sticky is pinned to the top of the viewport and add a shadow to it. Problem is, that the shadow itself somehow messes up the intersection detection and causes the shadow to flicker. I use `filter: drop-shadow` for shadow. Using `box-shadow` works fine, but I can't use it because in my case sticky is non-rectangular.

Here is an example. Intersection observer is not working properly in snippet iframe, but you can repeat flickering by clicking "Run code snippet", "Full page", right click, "Save as", and then open saved HTML.

```js
const ob = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      entry.target.classList.toggle('pinned', entry.intersectionRatio < 1);
    }
  },
  {
    threshold: [1],
    rootMargin: '-1px 0px 0px 0px',
  },
);
ob.observe(document.getElementById('sticky'));
```

```css
#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: khaki;
}
.pinned {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px red);
  /* this is fine: */
  /* box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px red; */
}

/* added by editor for demo purpose */
body {
  min-height: 500vh;
}

div[data-placeholder="A"] {
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div data-placeholder="A"></div>
<div id="sticky">
  I am sticky
</div>
```

How this can be solved?

Comment: After more testing, I think it is actually a bug. Filed it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1358819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I could not exactly reproduce the problem described in the question I can see that observing and toggling on the same element might produce flickering with the element slightly moving up and down.

To get round this, this snippet adds a 'sensor' pixel element which is what gets observed rather than the sticky element. As it moves out of the viewport the pinned class is added to the sticky element and as it comes back into the viewport the pinned class is removed. In this way the intersection observing and the stickiness are separated. There is no flickering.

```html
<style>
  #sensor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  
  #sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: khaki;
  }
  
  .pinned {
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px red);
    /* this is fine: */
    /* box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px red; */
  }
  
  body {
    /* just for demo to make sure we can scroll */
    min-height: 200vh;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br></div>
  <div id="sensor"></div>
  <div id="sticky">
    I am sticky
  </div>
  <script>
    const ob = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        for (const entry of entries) {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            document.querySelector('#sticky').classList.remove('pinned');
          } else {
            document.querySelector('#sticky').classList.add('pinned');
          }
        }
      });
    ob.observe(document.querySelector('#sensor'));
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives a solution to problem, however does not explain why `drop-shadow` messes up intersection observer, intuitively it should not change size of element. You can repeat flickering by clicking "Run code spippet", "Full page", right click, "Save as", and then open saved HTML. Intersection observer is not working properly in iframe.